# Overload return of a pointer with reference and pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, overloading

I got following code:

```
 class myarray 
 {  

    float* rawdata;

    float*   GetRawData () const noexcept { return rawdata; };
    float&   GetRawData () const noexcept { return rawdata; };
    const float&   GetRawData () const noexcept { return rawdata; };


 }
```

I get compiler error saying it is not possible to overload the first two member functions. Is it not possible for C++ to distinguish since we in a reference would have a different syntax when invoking the function

Comment: Correct, it is not possible.

Comment: Any [decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), class or tutorial should have mentioned it.

Comment: When writing `myarray x; x.GetRawData();` which function should be called? The compiler could not decide. Thus it is not allowed.

Comment: *since we in a reference would have a different syntax when invoking the function* That's not really true. They would both be invoked by writing `GetRawData()`. What we do with the return value is not something the compiler takes into consideration when choosing an overload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it not possible for C++ to distinguish

It is not. Overloading is possible with different parameter lists, and in the case of member functions, ref/const qualifiers. But not by return values. Your overloads have identical parameter lists and ref/const qualifiers, so they cannot overload each other.

> since we in a reference would have a different syntax when invoking the function

No, we wouldn't. The invokation is identical in both cases:

```
this->GetRawData()
```